# Purpose of index bits in CPU caching

Tags: caching, cpu-cache

The current [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache#Cache_entry_structure) about CPU caches says the following:

> The index describes which cache row (which cache line) that the data
>   has been put in.

I doubt that this is true, because as far as I've understood the way how caches work, the index bits select the set in which an item can be stored. A set consists of multiple cache lines (aka. cache blocks). The tag bits then are used to identify cache lines.

Am I right?

Comment: The "Example" section on the page you cited explains how the index describes which cache row (of the possible cache rows that address could be cached at) actually holds the data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about hardware details, and isn't really relevant to programming

Comment: I know this question might be called off-topic, but what stackexchange site fits better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing yourself with 2 different mapping schemes. The term **set** is used only when mapping used is **set-associative**. It has no meaning if mapping used is **direct mapping**.These different mappings are clearly explained in the link you provided in your question.

Please Note that the statement

> The index describes which cache row (which cache line) that the data
>   has been put in.

is  For **Direct mapping** scheme, where the number of bits in the index field describe the number of rows in cache memory. Meaning if index field is of **x** bits then there are **2 to the power x** rows in cache memory. And the offset is used to locate which byte we want to read in a particular row, in case our memory is byte addressable.

For **set-associative** scheme, our entire cache memory is divided into sets. The field **index** now is no longer there but it is divided into two fields namely **set** and **offset**, where set describes which set we are concerned with and offset is used to specify which byte in a set we want in case the memory is byte addressable.

Comment: As direct mapping is only a special case of a set-associative scheme (1-way set-associative), we was thinking about a cache consisting of one set which then contains all cache line. For that reason I used the term **set** when talking about direct mapping and I got confused. Thanks for the clarification.